# Correctly editing Web GUI with Tizen

Tags: javascript, tizen, tizen-web-app

I am trying to build a Tizen Web Application for wearables using TAU. 
I have this list:

```
<ul class="ui-listview" id="nearbyList">
        <li class="ui-listview-divider">Nearby</li>


        <li class="li-has-multiline li-has-thumb-left">
                <a href="contents/place1.html">Place 1
                <span class="ui-li-sub-text li-text-sub">Info 1</span>
                <span class="ui-li-sub-text li-text-sub">xxxx</span>
                <img src="../../../css/images/place1.png" class="ui-li-thumb-left">
                </a>
        </li>

        <li class="li-has-multiline li-has-thumb-left">
                <a href="index-old.html">Open Elements
                <span class="ui-li-sub-text li-text-sub">xxxx</span>
                <span class="ui-li-sub-text li-text-sub">xxxx</span>
                <img src="../../../css/images/open.png" class="ui-li-thumb-left">
                </a>
        </li>

    </ul>
```

which I need to edit using JS with data I fetch from the web. The problem is when I try to edit the list using JQuery, it doesn't seem to work and instead renders the new elements behind the existing list. Using the debugger Menu in Tizen Studio, I can see TAU heavily edits the HTML, resulting in my #nearbyList not containing the elements I specified above, therefore JQuery adding it and TAU not acknowledging it and updating accordingly.

This is the code I try to use to add elements to the list:

```
$('#nearbyList').append('<li class=\"ui-li-grid\"> <div>Finding Location</div> <div class=\"ui-processing\"></div></li>');//processing animation
```

Which instead renders this:

[image]

This is how I initialise my scripts:

```
<script src="lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/circle-helper.js"></script>

<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/lowBatteryCheck.js"></script>
<script src="lib/tau/wearable/js/tau.js"></script>
<script src="lib/jsSHA/sha1.js"></script>
<script src="js/web.js"></script>
<script src="js/location.js"></script>
```

Any help on how to correctly use JQuery with TAU to add elements to a list would be great.

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you use the addItem(HTMLElement item, index) of TAU to add item ?

Comment: That exists?! Thank you! It would be great for you to write an answer with an example so I can upvote it.

Comment: @Iqbalhossain I tried using .addItem as follows: https://imgur.com/a/3fYTh2W but it didn't seem to work correctly

Answer (score 0):

You may simply use JS to add item in list. I have create each item like below and add by a loop.

```
UL = document.getElementById("list");
li = document.createElement("LI");
var textnode = document.createTextNode("Title");
li.appendChild(textnode);
nodeA = document.createElement("A");
var textnode2 = document.createTextNode("Link");
nodeA.appendChild(textnode2);
span = document.createElement("SPAN");
var textnode3 = document.createTextNode("Content");
span.appendChild(textnode3);
li.appendChild(nodeA);
li.appendChild(span);
UL.appendChild(li);
```

It won't atleast break your TAU list.

Comment: Would it still support the rotating bezel scroll and the carousel effect like a tau list? Don't see any relevant CSS classes being added

Comment: Doesn't preserve the Carousel effect from the Listview widget :/. It instead adds it to the bottom where it doesn't scroll with the rotating watch bezel and obstructs the original carousel list

Comment: you have to add all the effect dynamically when you are adding a new item in the list

Comment: How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's little too late, but it might be good for future developers.
I removed `tau.js` include in html and added this after jQuery rendered all elements in list.

```
$.getScript( "lib/tau/wearable/js/tau.js" )
        .done(function( script, textStatus ) {
            console.log( 'Works!' );
        })
        .fail(function( jqxhr, settings, exception ) {
            console.log( "Triggered ajaxError handler." );
        });
```